# why does my code not giving me reverse number accurately

Tags: java

Java Code Example: i am facing issue when i insert 010 it shows only 1 instead of whole number and when i insert 200  it gave me reverse number only 2 while it should show me exact 002 how can i get exact number in reverse:

```
class Reverse{
    public static void main(String args[]){  
      int remander,sum=0;    
      int number=454;      
      while(n>0) // loop here
      {
           remander=n%10;  // Getting remainder
           sum=(sum*10)+remander;    
           number=number/10;   
      } 
        System.out.println("Reverse"+sum);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Because `010` is a number entered in octal notation. Not decimal.

Comment: What's with the quote in quote?

Comment: What does XML have to do with it? What does `**Output**("Reverse"+sum);` mean?

Comment: `Reverse.java:12: error: illegal start of expression: **Output**("Reverse"+sum);`

Comment: @MarquisofLorne It shows only 1 (digit)?

Comment: When you think of an integer, you aren't counting any leading zeros.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Very likely, but it's anybody's guess really. Up to the OP to clarify, entirely.

Comment: sorry dear strangers its my first question on stack overflow and i try to upload it many times but it show error there for i cant upload it properly there for i have just update my question sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Ask a Mathematics teacher.  The numbers 2 and 002 are the same number.  Now if you were talking about reversing a **string** then "2" and "002" are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that you are new to Java, and new to programming.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm going to add some extra advice that I don't normally offer, to help you get better faster.

1. Don't reuse a variable for more than one thing.  Use it for only one thing.  That means that if a variable holds you input, don't overwrite it with intermediate values.  Variables are (relatively) cheap, create another.  You can practice this by marking your variables `final` which will prevent you from changing their values after assigned.
2. Use meaningful variable names.  "r" is not a meaningful name.  "remainder" is a meaningful name.  This helps others immediately, and will help you later, when the program isn't fresh on your mind and you don't remember what "r" means.
3. Once you master not reusing variables, you will have a lot of variables.  Look for variables that are "set once and read once" and try to rearrange your code to remove them completely.  It will take some time to understand what I mean, but if you have heard of "refactoring" the idea is to remove the variable name because it isn't used twice (so it probably isn't a key part of your problem.

Now, applying these rules

```
  final int number = 454;      
  // get the number digits, smallest to largest
  int remainder = number;
  int accumulator = 0;
  while (remainder > 0) {
     final int digit = remainder % 10;
     accumulator = accumulator * 10 + digit;
     remainder = remainder / 10;
  }
  final int reversed = accumulator;
```

note that `digit` is never used twice

```
  final int number = 454;      
  // get the number digits, smallest to largest
  int remainder = number;
  int accumulator = 0;
  while (remainder > 0) {
     accumulator = accumulator * 10 + remainder % 10;
     remainder = remainder / 10;
  }
  final int reversed = accumulator;
```

Note that all that "logic" could have a really good name put to it, so we'll create a "method"

```
  public int reverse(int value) {
      int remainder = value;
      int accumulator = 0;
      while (remainder > 0) {
          accumulator = accumulator * 10 + remainder % 10;
          remainder = remainder / 10;
      }
      return accumulator;
  }
```

which cleans up the other code to

```
  final int number = 454;
  final int reversed = reverse(number);
```

or maybe even

```
  final int reversed = reverse(454);
```

Comment: Also, in Java, never start a number off with `0` if you are using a decimal number.  Numbers that start with `0` are octal numbers.  For example 09 is an invalid number in Java (because octal numbers don't have a `9` digit).

Comment: Your use of `digit` violates your own rule #3. I cannot see why you introduced it in the first place.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne You'll notice that I don't write my code once, but write it and revise it a few times.  The initial pass introduced `digit` which was then removed in subsequent rewrites.

Comment: Thanks dear i will keep your advice in my mind